# How can I emulate `uniq -d` in awk?

Tags: sed, awk, uniq

I've got a busybox system which doesn't have `uniq` and I'd like to generate a unique list of duplicated lines.

A plain `uniq` emulated in `awk` would be:

```
sort <filename> | awk '!($0 in a){a[$0]; print}'
```

How can I use `awk` (or `sed` for that matter, not `perl`) to accomplish:

```
sort <filename> | uniq -d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could do this (needn't sort it):

```
awk '{++a[$0]; if(a[$0] == 2) print}'
```

Comment: didn't know you could do associative arrays.

Comment: @Jamie: This is although exactly what you use in your first example, even if you thought it was actually a set.

Answer (score 6):

On a busybox system, you might need to save bytes. ;-)

```
awk ++a[\$0]==2
```

Comment: you can still get rid of two spaces.

Comment: and if you put `alias a='awk ++a[\$0]==2'` into your bashrc, you can get rid of all characters but one. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
# make some test data
seq 25 >/tmp/a
seq 3 3 25 >>/tmp/a
seq 5 5 25 >>/tmp/a
# run old command
sort -n /tmp/a | uniq -d
3
5
6
9
10
12
15
18
20
21
24
25
# run sed command 
sort -n /tmp/a | 
sed ':a;$bb;N;/^\([^\n]*\)\(\n\1\)*$/ba;:b;/^\([^\n]*\)\(\n\1\)*/{s//\1/;P};D' 
3
5
6
9
10
12
15
18
20
21
24
25
```